# Using QObject instead of a container

Tags: qt

After reading up on the interesting parent-child system of `QObject` I am wondering how common it is for Qt developers to use this in place of a more traditional container. Assuming memory contiguity is not a requirement, it seems this offers some interesting features.

For example, you could have a `QObject` and give it children of different types, and then find all children easily based on their types, giving QObject a dynamic heterogenous container-like feature, as opposed to the required homogenous collection of a traditional container.

And `QObject` naturally manages the memory of its children, which is convenient as well.

Is this a common use of this feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QObject::findChildren` could be much slower than storing your objects in a normal container like QList because:

1. It iterates over all children each time. It even searches recursively (but this can be disabled).
2. It performs runtime type check.
3. It constructs new QList each time. This can be slow and expensive it there are many objects in result.

All the above it unnecessary if you just use `QList<Type*> my_objects`. Also in this case:

1. You can name your collection. `QList<QPushButton*> panic_buttons` is clearer than `findChildren<QPushButton*>()`.
2. You can have several collections of objects of the same type.

If you want to make a heterogenous container, you can use `QHash<any_type_identifier, QObject*>`. It will be faster.

Maybe, findChildren approach may be simplier sometimes. But if you have many objects or a complicated class, you'd better use normal containers. You can still use QObject's memory management with them without any problems.

Comment: What's more - things should be generally used in a way they were made for, and `QObject` was not designed as a container. It would be very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

As @PavelStrakhov states, using QObject::findChildren could be slower. However, one method I use is to combine storing objects in QList as well as having the QObject parent hierarchy. It's based on doing something like this: -

```
class BaseObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:

        static BaseObject* FindObject(unsigned int id); // find object by id

    private:
        unsigned int m_id;

        static unsigned int s_nextId; // next id for a new BaseObject
        static QList<QBaseObject*> s_objectsList; // list of all BaseObject-type instances
};
```

All objects now inherit BaseObject instead of QObject. When a new class is created, the constructor of the BaseObject will set the item's id, increment s_nextId and finally, the object is added to s_objectsList. Finding objects is now a simple matter of searching the static object list.

This may not suit the design of the application that you're developing, but it certainly helped me, especially when using the QGraphicsView / QGraphicsScene system. In that situation, the BaseObject is derived from QGraphicsObject.

Of-course, if you're using a lot of standard widgets, you're less likely to want to create new classes for them all, but it's an option that can suit some designs.

Comment: I thought it might, depending on what you're developing, but decided to post it just in-case it helped.

Comment: Global variables are an evil. And this is almost global variable. Also I think one list per class is not enough in most cases.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov, are you suggesting that static class members are the same as global variables? If not, can you please explain?

Comment: Yes. Static variables are application-wide, so you should use them only if you have to. Generic container is not this case.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but it depends on the definition of "application-wide". In the case of the given example, the static members are defined in the private section of the class, so their scope of access is limited, like any other private member. Of-course the FindObject exposes them, but so would a generic container. Also, whilst their lifetime is that of the application, the same would be required for a generic container in this situation.